# Restore session after accidental keyboard interrupt

Tags: python-3.x, keyboardinterrupt

I was tagging some NLP data in python and accidentally pressed control + c, cancelling the data that I was building up (in the form of a list). Is there anyway to recover the data or session that I was working on without having to start over? Thanks

Comment: Had you by chance printed the list at any point? Like do you have any idea where your script was in the execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - no,
as it is not storing anywhere except RAM, that is clearing after you stopped process.

Only if you had verbose enough logs or system does some backups from time to time.